# SQL using data field twice

Tags: t-sql, union

I currently have the following:

```
    SELECT        TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, 
                         TblStaff.Fullname AS TutorFullName, TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress, TblSchoolManagementYears.txtYearTutor, TblSchoolManagementYears.txtAsstYearTutor
FROM            TblPupilManagementPupils INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementForms ON TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForm = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff ON TblSchoolManagementForms.txtFormTutor = TblStaff.User_Code INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementYears ON TblPupilManagementPupils.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear AND 
                         TblSchoolManagementForms.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear
WHERE       TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear > 6

UNION

SELECT        TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, 
                         TblStaff.Fullname AS TutorFullName, TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress, TblSchoolManagementYears.txtYearTutor, TblSchoolManagementYears.txtAsstYearTutor
FROM            TblPupilManagementPupils INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementForms ON TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForm = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff ON TblSchoolManagementForms.txtAsstFormTutor = TblStaff.User_Code INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementYears ON TblPupilManagementPupils.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear AND 
                         TblSchoolManagementForms.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear
WHERE       TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear > 6
```

This is working beautifully, but I need to add in some additional columns that also link back to `TblStaff.User_Code` My design currently looks like this, the highlighted fields are the ones I need to link in my query:

[image: Table Design]

What I need to do is add 2 additional columns, 1 for HoYEmail and one for AsstHoYEmail using `txtYearTutor` linked by `User_Code` as `TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress AS HoYEmail` and the `AsstYearTutor` linked by `User_Code` as `TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress AS AsstHoYEmail` all grouped by `TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID`

Producing something like this:

[image: Output]

Any tips gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, I ended up completely re-writing this query to get it to work using correlation names for the staff table.

```
SELECT        TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, 
                         TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress AS TutorEmail, TblStaff_1.SchoolEmailAddress AS HoYEmail, TblStaff_2.SchoolEmailAddress AS AsstHoYEmail
FROM            TblStaff INNER JOIN
                         TblPupilManagementPupils INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementForms ON TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForm = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm ON 
                         TblStaff.User_Code = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtFormTutor INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementYears ON TblPupilManagementPupils.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff AS TblStaff_1 ON TblSchoolManagementYears.txtYearTutor = TblStaff_1.User_Code INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff AS TblStaff_2 ON TblSchoolManagementYears.txtAsstYearTutor = TblStaff_2.User_Code
WHERE        (TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear > 6) AND (TblPupilManagementPupils.intSystemStatus = 1)

UNION

SELECT        TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSchoolID, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtSurname, TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForename, 
                         TblStaff.SchoolEmailAddress AS TutorEmail, TblStaff_1.SchoolEmailAddress AS HoYEmail, TblStaff_2.SchoolEmailAddress AS AsstHoYEmail
FROM            TblStaff INNER JOIN
                         TblPupilManagementPupils INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementForms ON TblPupilManagementPupils.txtForm = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtForm ON 
                         TblStaff.User_Code = TblSchoolManagementForms.txtAsstFormTutor INNER JOIN
                         TblSchoolManagementYears ON TblPupilManagementPupils.intNCYear = TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff AS TblStaff_1 ON TblSchoolManagementYears.txtYearTutor = TblStaff_1.User_Code INNER JOIN
                         TblStaff AS TblStaff_2 ON TblSchoolManagementYears.txtAsstYearTutor = TblStaff_2.User_Code
WHERE        (TblSchoolManagementYears.intNCYear > 6) AND (TblPupilManagementPupils.intSystemStatus = 1)
```